# How do I capture select value from dropdown menu in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have cities table and profiles table. Below is the models of both:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :city
end
```

I am trying to create a dropdown list for cities in profile view page.

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :city_id %>
        <%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@city.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }) %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Update Profile" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the ProfilesController:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    def new
            @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
            @profile = Profile.new
            @city = City.all
    end

    def create
            @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
            @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)
            if @profile.save
                flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
                redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] ) 
            else
                render action: :new 
            end
    end
end
```

How do I add city_id column in the profiles table, I am unable to capture city_id from the above ProfilesController.
I tried to `@city = City.find( params[:city_id] )` in "ProfilesController", 
"Def create", and I got this error:

> Couldn't find City with 'id'=

Please advice.

Comment: Hello, had you permit your params ?

Comment: @RonanLouarn Thanks for your concern. I had permitted params `private
      def profile_params
        params.require(:profile).permit(:country, :city)
      end`
      
      `def only_current_user
        @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
        redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user 
      end
 end`

Comment: Ok, can you show error message please?

Comment: **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProfilesController#create
Couldn't find City with 'id'=**

Extracted source (around line #11):

      `@user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
      @profile = @user.build_profile(profile_params)
             @city = City.find( params[:city_id] )
      if @profile.save
         flash[:success] = "Profile Updated!"
         redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] ) `

Answer (score 0):

try whitelisting `city_id` instead of `city`

```
private def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:country, :city)
end
```

Change you associations-

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :city
end
```

`city_id` column should be in that model where you are using `belongs_to` association

Comment: ,Thanks for your concern. I did that it worked but in database under "city_id", it's reflecting as "nil". `<#<Profile id: 2, country: "usa", created_at: "2017-07-11 17:28:53", updated_at: "2017-07-11 17:28:53", **city_id: nil**, user_id: 2>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace

```
has_one :city
```

by

```
belongs_to :city
```

in your profile model and in your city model replace

```
belongs_to :profile
```

by

```
has_many :profiles
```

Comment: I did that it worked but in database under "city_id", it's reflecting as "nil". **<#<Profile id: 3, country: "india", created_at: "2017-07-11 17:28:53", updated_at: "2017-07-11 17:28:53", city_id: nil, user_id: 2>**